# C++ SDL2 - Incomprehensible link error

Tags: c++, linker, sdl-2

I setup SDL2 under C++ CDT Eclipse.
I added the include path "........SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include", the library path "........SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib" and added the libraries 1."mingw32" 2."SDL2main" 3."SDL2".
So now, if I add a main.cpp with this content:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{

    return 0;
}
```

I can build the project fine, but if I use this:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

The project can't build and I get this error:

> Info: Internal Builder is used for build g++ "-IO:\Eclipse CDT
>   Workspace\SDL OpenGL Lab\Libraries\SDL2\include\SDL2" -O0 -g3
>   -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\main.cpp"  g++ "-LO:\Eclipse CDT Workspace\SDL OpenGL Lab\Libraries\SDL2\lib" -o
>   "SDL OpenGL Lab.exe" main.o -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  O:\Eclipse
>   CDT Workspace\SDL OpenGL
>   Lab\Libraries\SDL2\lib/libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o): In function
>   `console_main':
>   /Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:140:
>   undefined reference to`SDL_main' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

I simply wonder me why this error is depending on my main method, I want to use the main method I want.
Why this is so, how I can fix this ?

Comment: Does it really matter that much that you have to use `int main(int argc, char* args[])` I've never once come across a situation where I've thought 'man I wish I didn't have to have parameters in my main function'

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you're stuck with it.  I also preferred a simpler main, but SDL doesn't support it.

Here's a little more on SDL and main in the Windows world.  It doesn't say *why* you need their version of main -- but you do.

> I get "Undefined reference to 'SDL_main'" ...
>
> Make sure that you are declaring main() as:
>
> #include "SDL.h"
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])

https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and had to go through a lot of manipulations.
What I have found is the simple line #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED before calling SDL.h. SDL has his own main that's why, I think.
For example, in my .h files, I write everytime this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED 
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
```